# Access on base class of template prior to expansion of the template being derived from

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, protected

I'm trying to publicly derive a class from a template that will make it inherit from a base class and get access on protected members.  But before the template is expanded it doesn't have those rights, so it can't use a Base member as a template parameter:

```
using Fun = void (*)();

class Base {
protected:
    // friend class Derived; // ...need this to eliminate complaint
    static void something();
};

template<Fun F>
class Variant : public Base {};

class Derived : public Variant<&Base::something> { // `something()` is protected
public:
    void somethingElse() {
        something(); // doesn't complain about this `something()`
    }
};

int main() {}
```

The weird bit about this to me was that friending it worked at all.  I wondered if I might "sneak Derived in the door" by putting a public virtual inheritance from Base before the Variant:

```
class Derived : public virtual Base, public Variant<&Base::something>
```

That didn't help.

**Question:** is there some other trick for avoiding explicit mention of all derived classes in Base, yet still have access to pick protected members out of it for template parameters?

*(Note: Trying this on an older gcc, 4.6.3, looks like even the friending doesn't help in that case.  So it seems support for that is somewhat new.)*

Comment: Related: [CWG 372](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue372) and [CWG 580](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue580). It seems even current versions of clang++ and g++ do not implement the proposed resolution for the latter defect.

Comment: @dyp I'm thinking that's probably "the answer" or as close as we'll get.  Want to make it one?

Answer (score 1):

Stick the offending access into a metafunction. Derive the metafunction class from the base.

```
template<typename B>
struct something_variant : public B {
    typedef Variant< & B::something > type;
};

class Derived : public something_variant<Base>::type {
    …
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bca00455bd3daca

Regarding CWG 372, the critical text in the resolution is this:

> [A]ccess checking of base-specifiers must be deferred until the entire base-specifier-list has been seen.

This was already accepted in C++11, so it's interesting that your example is rejected. And, [plugging](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3121054805bb025b) the relevant example code *from the C++11 standard* into recent Clang and GCC demonstrates that they simply did not implement the deferral. It's at least a little unsurprising, since implementation requires some data structure to represent a set of deferred access checks… fairly high effort for a corner case.